# React components rendering with variable names

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a unknown list of react components to render.

```
// this is a react component
var DefaultModule = require('./DefaultModule.js');
```

`<DefaultModule/>`  <--- this will output something because the name is 
    exactly the class name inside `DefaultModule.js`

but if I do

```
// this is a react component
var sssss = require('./DefaultModule.js');
```

`<sssss/>`  <--- this will not work

so is there a way I can take a list of component names and render them accordingly?  Thanks.

p.s: the react component looks like this

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     1123123123123123 hahaha small test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured out the answer from a discussion thread...

Yes I can do that but the react component must start in capital letter. so `Sssss` will work `sssss` will now.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365

`The key is to use a capitalized variable name (Component) otherwise React will treat it as a built-in DOM element.`